# Determine the blackberry processor programmatically?

Tags: blackberry, processor

I want to determine the processor speed of the blackberry device programmatically.
Based on the processor speed i want to display few things on the app. 
Please tell me how do i determine this programmatically.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that. But you can determine [device name](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getDeviceName%28%29) and [software version](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getPlatformVersion%28%29) and use your own local dictionary with technical specifications of every device model.

Comment: Thank you rafael for the reply. I have 2 blackberry phone. One is high end and the other is lower end phone. Both are touch enabled. I am building an application which works fine in the high end phone because of the good processor but does not work fine on the low end phone because of its low processor. To solve this problem i need to determine the processor during runtime. So there is there any way to  do this.

Comment: There is no API to determine the processor. But you can implement code to benchmark current processor. Do some benchmarking on high-end phone and create some metrics to rely on. For instance - drawing 100000 triangles per second. And upon starting your app calculate current processor performance and compare it with these metrics. If it is above - ok, if below - show message and quit application.

Comment: Thanks Rafael that can be helpful